# BASH csv parsing using IFS=, where some fields contain the separator, ie an address

Tags: bash, parsing, csv, ifs

I'm trying to parse a csv file that gets generated from a MySQL database using `IFS=,`, but some of the fields contain a `,` that shouldn't be treated as a separator.

For instance, the first line is:
`"012345678","abcdefgh","Smith, John","1234 Main St. Somewhere, state"`

What I'm getting in return is:
`"012345678","abcdefgh","Smith","John","1234 Main St. Somewhere","state"`

I'm trying to assign each field to a variable, but the script is getting hung up on the commas that aren't actual field separators.

Answer (score 0):

You can use gnu awk here to split string like this:

```
s='"012345678","abcdefgh","Smith, John","1234 Main St. Somewhere, state"'
echo "$s" | gawk 'BEGIN{ FPAT="\"[^\"]*\"" } {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print $i}'
"012345678"
"abcdefgh"
"Smith, John"
"1234 Main St. Somewhere, state"
```